# Remove duplicated rows of a `list[str]` type column in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a DataFrame with a column that contains lists of strings. I want to filter the DataFrame to drop rows with duplicated values of the list column.

For example,

```py
import polars as pl

# Create a DataFrame with a list[str] type column
data = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "values": [
        ["a", "a", "a"], # first two rows are duplicated
        ["a", "a", "a"],
        ["b", "b", "b"],
        ["c", "d", "e"]
    ]
})

print(data)

shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ values          │
│ --- ┆ ---             │
│ i64 ┆ list[str]       │
╞═════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["a", "a", "a"] │
│ 2   ┆ ["a", "a", "a"] │
│ 3   ┆ ["b", "b", "b"] │
│ 4   ┆ ["c", "d", "e"] │
└─────┴─────────────────┘
```

Desired result:

```py
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ values          │
│ --- ┆ ---             │
│ i64 ┆ list[str]       │
╞═════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["a", "a", "a"] │
│ 3   ┆ ["b", "b", "b"] │
│ 4   ┆ ["c", "d", "e"] │
└─────┴─────────────────┘
```

Using the `unique` method doesn't work for type `list[str]` (it works when list contains numeric types, though).

```py
data.unique(subset="values")

ComputeError: grouping on list type is only allowed if the inner type is numeric
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast the strings to categorical:

```
(df.with_columns(pl.col("values").cast(pl.List(pl.Categorical)))
   .unique(subset="values", maintain_order=True))
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ values          │
│ --- ┆ ---             │
│ i64 ┆ list[cat]       │
╞═════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["a", "a", "a"] │
│ 3   ┆ ["b", "b", "b"] │
│ 4   ┆ ["c", "d", "e"] │
└─────┴─────────────────┘
```

Comment: Using `pl.format("[{}]", col("values").arr.join(", "))` (which I took from one of your answers to another post) instead of casting to pl.Categorical seems a smidge faster in my application. I still like your answer better since it is cleaner.

Comment: Also, in my application I've found that doing this – both casting and using format – in lazy mode returns a non-deterministic number of rows, which looks like a bug to me. I will try to create a sharable example when I have time.

Comment: That's surprising. Can you try `df.with_columns(struct = pl.col("values").arr.to_struct()).unique(subset="struct", maintain_order=True)`

Comment: or `df.groupby(pl.col("values").arr.to_struct().alias("group"), maintain_order=True).first()`

Comment: @Maturin Using a struct actually requires sorting by length if the lengths differ, so ignore that suggestion. I cannot replicate `pl.format` being faster, it is several magnitiudes slower in my testing. `.groupby(col().cast().alias("group"), maintain_order=True).first().drop("group")` comes out slightly faster than `cast().unique()` for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are all of the same length like in your example, you could (and maybe *should*) split them up such that each entry has its own corresponding column. Although you can sometimes make it work, DataFrames really aren't intended for use with entries that are themselves non-scalar. What I'm suggesting is something that looks like this:

```py
In[1]:  import polars as pl

        data = pl.DataFrame([[1, "a", "a", "a"],
                             [2, "a", "a", "a"],
                             [3, "b", "b", "b"],
                             [4, "c", "d", "e"]],
                            schema=["id"]+[f"value{i}" for i in range(3)])
        print(data)

Out[1]: shape: (4, 4)
        ┌─────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
        │ id  ┆ value0 ┆ value1 ┆ value2 │
        │ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
        │ i64 ┆ str    ┆ str    ┆ str    │
        ╞═════╪════════╪════════╪════════╡
        │ 1   ┆ a      ┆ a      ┆ a      │
        │ 2   ┆ a      ┆ a      ┆ a      │
        │ 3   ┆ b      ┆ b      ┆ b      │
        │ 4   ┆ c      ┆ d      ┆ e      │
        └─────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

From there, a straightforward call to `data.unique(subset=["value0", "value1", "value2"])` will accomplish what you want.

Comment: That's a great suggestion. In my application the lists are not the same length, though.

Answer (score 0):

you could:

1. use with_columns to create a new column containing the joined array
2. use unique on that new column
3. select only the array column again (use drop or select, I did not benchmark but I believe that select is faster than drop)

Following code is just demonstrative, do it with a lazyframe to speed things up

```
import polars as pl
data = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "values": [
        ["a", "a", "a"], # first two rows are duplicated
        ["a", "a", "a"],
        ["b", "b", "b"],
        ["c", "d", "e"]
    ]
})
print(data)

shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ values          │
│ --- ┆ ---             │
│ i64 ┆ list[str]       │
╞═════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["a", "a", "a"] │
│ 2   ┆ ["a", "a", "a"] │
│ 3   ┆ ["b", "b", "b"] │
│ 4   ┆ ["c", "d", "e"] │
└─────┴─────────────────┘

data = data.with_columns(
    pl.col('values').arr.join('').alias('tmp')
).unique(
    subset='tmp',
    maintain_order=True
    ).drop('tmp')
print(data)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ values          │
│ --- ┆ ---             │
│ i64 ┆ list[str]       │
╞═════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["a", "a", "a"] │
│ 3   ┆ ["b", "b", "b"] │
│ 4   ┆ ["c", "d", "e"] │
└─────┴─────────────────┘
```